# Number of possible combinations of N variables when their sum is S and the variables have a value of 1 or more

Tags: combinatorics

> Give the number of possible combinations of N variables when their sum is S. The variables can only have values of 1 or more.

For example when N = 3 and S = 5, the answer is 6 because the number of combinations possible for $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5$ are:

3, 1, 1

1, 3, 1

1, 1, 3

2, 2, 1

2, 1, 2

1, 2, 2

So far I've come up with $S-1 \choose N-1$ but I don't think it works for all cases.

Comment: Your formula looks good to me. [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a well-known method for deriving it.

Comment: (converted my comment into a fuller answer in the interests of completeness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula $S-1 \choose N-1$ looks correct. A well-known aid to deriving it is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The stars and bars method can be used as follows.

Suppose we have $S$ stars arranged in a line, and we want to partition them into $N$ non-empty groups by placing each of $N-1$ bars between two stars. For instance, for $S = 5$ and $N = 3$ we could place the two bars to make three groups like this:

$$ * * | * | ** $$

This is equivalent to your problem of counting how many ways $N$ positive integers can be combined to sum to $S$. The arrangement above corresponds to the combination $(2, 1, 2)$.

There are $S-1$ locations we could place the $N-1$ bars, so the formula $S-1 \choose N-1$ counts all of the possibilities.